# i want to make a 5% percent on the number that i wrote in Reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

````
@client.command()
async def credit(ctx, member: discord.Member, Reason):
    await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.message.author.name},, Transfer Fees: $`{Reason}`, Amount : $`{Reason}` type these numbers to confirm :**')
    await ctx.send('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/783308936622112789/820678247984398386/unknown.png')
    def check(m):
        return m.content == '81592'
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await member.send(f':atm:  |  Transfer Receipt\n```You have received ${Reason} from user {ctx.message.author.name}, (ID: {ctx.message.author.id})\nReason: No reason provided```')
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=3)
    await ctx.send(f':moneybag: **| {ctx.message.author.name}, has transferred `${Reason}` to** {member.mention} ')
````

i want in the {Reason}
i i write
#credit @test 10
in the Fee: {reason*5%} but it don't work
what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think this should work:

```
Reason_percentage = ""

try:
    
    Reason_percentage += str(int(Reason) *5 / 100)

except TypeError:
    
    await ctx.send("Error: Please type a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string you take out of the message as integer with `int(WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_CONVERT)` and the you can `multiplicate` it with `5 / 100` because `%` (probably) is another calculating option